# Output Multiple Objects to CosmosDB with Azure Function (Isolated Process)

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, dotnet-isolated

I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to output multiple documents to Azure CosmosDB from an Azure Function isolated process.

I understand "Because .NET isolated projects run in a separate worker process, bindings can't take advantage of rich binding classes, such as ICollector, IAsyncCollector, and CloudBlockBlob." Ref. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#bindings

However, I am assuming there must still be a way to insert multiple records in a single execution of my timer function.

**In the following code, I can easily insert a single record, but how can I adapt this code to insert an array or list of records?**

I found [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-output?tabs=isolated-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-csharp#queue-trigger-write-docs-using-iasynccollector-c) but it doesn't seem to articulate how I can apply this code within the context of a timer function.

```
[Function("MyFunction")]
public async Task<MultiResponse> Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] MyInfo myTimer)
{
    var result = await _dataService.GetData();

    return new MultiResponse()
    {
        Document = new MyDocument
        {
            id = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
            message = "hello world"
        }
    };
}
public class MultiResponse
{
    [CosmosDBOutput("MyDatabase", "MyCollection",
        ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDbConnectionString", CreateIfNotExists = true)]
    public MyDocument Document { get; set; }
}
public class MyDocument
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried imperatively inserting the docs instead of using a binding?

Comment: Have you tried making a `List<MultiResponse>` and populating it from your service response or similar?

Comment: @TanveerBadar Thanks for your suggestion!  Your advice lead me to my answer (posted below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the output binding method which appears to be lacking in support in the isolated process, I was able to successfully use the SDK directly to insert the docs!

Ref. https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3

NUGET package:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos
```

Code sample:

```
CosmosClient client = new CosmosClient("https://mycosmosaccount.documents.azure.com:443/", "mysupersecretkey");
Database database = await client.CreateDatabaseIfNotExistsAsync("MyDatabaseName");
Container container = await database.CreateContainerIfNotExistsAsync(
    "MyContainerName",
    "/partitionKeyPath",
    400);

// Create an item
dynamic testItem = new { id = "MyTestItemId", partitionKeyPath = "MyTestPkValue", details = "it's working", status = "done" };
ItemResponse<dynamic> createResponse = await container.CreateItemAsync(testItem);
```

Comment: I have always strongly recommended using the SDK anyway. That way you have full control over retries etc.